# Quickly mark all emails as read?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Is there a way to quickly mark all emails as read instead of going over each one of them manually ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Menubar
1. Edit -> Select All
2. Message -> Mark -> As Read

[image: select all]

[image: mark as rea]

Answer (score 1):

Select all the mails you want using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click (one by one), <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click (a range), or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (all in mailbox), then either right-click or <kbd>Control</kbd>-click and select `Mark -> As Read`. This option is also available through the menu: `Message -> Mark -> As Read`. The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> will also do the same thing.